# hasManyThrough polymorphic relation

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I have a `student` model,a `favorite` model and media models eg `music`,`video` etc. I want to implement `hasManyThrough` ploymorphic relation in which the through model is `favorite` and then stores these favorites in `favorite` table in my case mongoDB. Am using loopback3 and its documentation isn't clear about this topic.Any lead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your models would look like this:

**common/models/student.json**

```
{
  "name": "Student",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {

  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "favorites": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Favorite",
      "foreignKey": "studentId"
    },
    "videos": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Video",
      "foreignKey": "studentId",
      "through": "Favorite",
      "keyThrough": "favoriteId"
    },
    "musics": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Music",
      "foreignKey": "studentId",
      "through": "Favorite",
      "keyThrough": "favoriteId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

**common/models/video.json**

```
{
  "name": "Video",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {

  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "favorites": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Favorite",
      "foreignKey": "videoId"
    },
    "students": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Student",
      "foreignKey": "videoId",
      "through": "Favorite",
      "keyThrough": "studentId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [
  ],
  "methods": {}
}
```

**common/models/favorite.json**

```
{
  "name": "Favorite",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {

  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "student": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Student",
      "foreignKey": "studentId"
    },
    "video": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Video",
      "foreignKey": "videoId"
    },
    "music": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Music",
      "foreignKey": "musicId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Then, you simply need to POST a new `Favorite` item with the attributes `studentId` and `videoId` to add the new relation.

***EDIT: Added music.json***

**common/models/music.json**

```
{
  "name": "Music",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {

  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "favorites": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Favorite",
      "foreignKey": "musicId"
    },
    "students": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Student",
      "foreignKey": "musicId",
      "through": "Favorite",
      "keyThrough": "studentId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [
  ],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Comment: This seems understandable but I need some few clarifications.1. can this work with other media eg music,quote,art and post in the same `favorite` table? 2. How do I get the `media type`...like video or quote or music..

Comment: 1. Your Favorite table can have multiple foreign keys. Eg: studentId, videoId, musicId. And some of them might stay NULL if necessary (but you always need the studentId of course). I updated my answer accordingly.
2. There is no *media type* that exist out the box. You need to create your own table with your own attributes. Then you can use the *LoopBack storage component* to upload a file - and link the uploaded file path to one of your custom attributes.